# How do I check the neighbors of the cells around me in a 2D array (C++)?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

So I'm trying to check if the cells surrounding the current cell of any given 2D array have a certain value (0 or 1) and depending on the value I want to count the total amount (total 1 values surrounding the current cell) however I'm not sure how to grab the positions below is some psuedocode I wrote that I think will consider each general position for a cell to be in however I'm not completely certain it is correct, and if it is correct I'm not sure how to grab the surrounding cells. Its not necessary to write out the whole code but basically I'm looking for conditions for positions to check for in future nested if statements that will of these big if statements such as array 
`if array([xPosition+1][yPosition+1] == 1)`

Here is the pesudocode

```
if (xPosition==0 && yPosition==0) {


    } else if (xPosition==rows && yPosition==columns) {

    } else if (xPosition==rows && yPosition==0) {

    } else if (xPosition==0 && yPosition==columns) {

    } else if (xPosition==0) {

    } else if (xPosition==rows) {

    } else if (yPosition==0) {

    } else if (yPosition==columns) {

    } else {

    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? In general you have just to check your currentCellIndex + or - 1 against your map borders to prevent accessing something outside your map, and when currentCellIndex +/- 1 is inside your map count that value.

Comment: This is for an assignment where I am supposed to run a simulation, the rules state depending on the surrounding cells  the current cell can go from being populated to not populated or vice versa. So I need to know if the surrounding cells are populated or not.

Comment: This sounds like [Conways Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) which is a common task for learning. A simple trick is to make the array larger (with a border). Thus, you don't need to check for boundaries in reading. You just have to adjust your loops for evaluation/writing to skip the boundary cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use nested loops

```
int sum{0};
for (int x{std::max(xPosition, 1) - 1}; x < std::min(xPosition + 2, columns); ++x) {
    for (int y{std::max(yPosition, 1) - 1}; y < std::min(xPosition + 2, rows); ++y) {
        if (x == xPosition && y == yPosition) continue;
        sum += array[x][y];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code is self explanatory and I have added the comments

```
bool isSafe(int xPosition, int yPosition, 
        int rows, int columns) { // checking the boundry
            return (xPosition >= 0 && xPosition < rows &&
                yPosition >= 0 && yPosition < columns);
        }


void checkNeighbours(int xPosition, int yPosition, 
                        int rows, int columns) {
        // Considering only 4 directions up, down , right, left                    
        int count = 0;
        if(isSafe(xPosition - 1, yPosition)) { // one cell up
            if(array[xPosition - 1][yPosition] == 1) {
                count ++;
            }
        }           

        if(isSafe (xPosition + 1, yPosition)) { // one cell down
            if(array[xPosition + 1][yPosition] == 1) {
                count ++;
            }
        }

        if(isSafe(xPosition, yPosition - 1)) { // one cell left
            if(array[xPosition][yPosition - 1] == 1) {
                count ++;
            }
        }

        if(isSafe(xPosition, yPosition + 1)) { // one cell right
            if(array[xPosition][yPosition + 1] == 1) {
                count ++;
            }
        }

        // use count for whatever
    }
```